# Cocos2d: are there any possible run time errors if two sprites run the same CCAnimation from CCAnimationCache at the same time?

Tags: ios, caching, animation, cocos2d-iphone

Not sure if the question is clear, but I found this and was wondering if there would be any conflicts in having this **runExplosionAnimation** method that is called every time a specific sprite has to explode. In the game I am developing there can be 20 sprites like this in the screen and I am wondering if it is ok to have have them to share the same animation (see **animationByName:@"anAnimation"**) or if this might cause some **runtime errors if two sprites are exploding at the same time.**

```
-(void) runExplosionAnimation
{
[self stopAllActions];

CCAnimation* anim = [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] animationByName:@"anAnimation"];
if(anim!=nil){
    [self runAction:[CCSequence actions: [CCAnimate actionWithDuration:0.4f animation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:false],  [CCHide action],  nil]];
}
else{
    [self loadSharedAnimationIfNeeded];
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not encountered issues yet, but with fewer than 20 possible simultaneous targets. However, reading cocos2d (2.0) code, the CCAnimation object is pretty much a POCO (plain objective-c object :) ) : it does not seem to maintain any kind of state. CCAnimate does that. So the objects are pretty much 'read only', are very unlikely to change after being placed in cache, and i cant see a condition that would cause an issue with any of the getter methods of the class. I feel safe with that, highly unlikely to happen with the threading model in use.

Comment: a very clear answer. Definetely a step forward in my still poor understanding of the Cocos2d framework. I am now curious to understand more about the threading model in use :).